# Install Opencv 3.0.0 on centos 6

Tags: python, opencv, centos6

I have installed Opencv 3.0.0 on centos referred  http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/ ,and after having some building package issue i have reached and installed successfully but not able to find cv2.so.

I have searched using sudo find / -name "cv2.so"

In centos i have Python 2.6 and in virtualenv Python 2.7.5 .

I have tried using git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git.

when it won't work then i have installed beta version.

```
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /path/to/opencv-build/opencv-3.0.0-beta/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..

output : 

Detected version of GNU GCC: 44 (404)
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib64/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.3", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib64/libz.so (found version "1.2.3") 
-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib64/libIlmImf.so
-- checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   package 'gtk+-3.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   package 'libavcodec' not found
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   package 'libavformat' not found
-- checking for module 'libavutil'
--   package 'libavutil' not found
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   package 'libswscale' not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - not found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- found IPP (ICV version): 8.2.1 [8.2.1]
-- at: /path/to/opencv-build/opencv-3.0.0-beta/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is exact version "2.7.5")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.6.6", but required is at least "3.4" (found /usr/bin/python)
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.6.6", but required is at least "3.2" (found /usr/bin/python)
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0-beta =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 2.6.32-042stab092.2 x86_64
--     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/gmake
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.4.7)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc imgcodecs videoio highgui ml features2d calib3d objdetect photo video shape stitching superres ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera cuda cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 python3 viz
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.23)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.28.8)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.3)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        /usr/lib64/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0202)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib64/libpng.so (ver 1.2.49)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib64/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 3.9.4)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib64/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib64/libImath.so /usr/lib64/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib64/libIex.so /usr/lib64/libHalf.so /usr/lib64/libIlmThread.so (ver 1.6.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.1.2)
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       codec:                     NO
--       format:                    NO
--       util:                      NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       gentoo-style:              NO
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 0.10.29)
--       video:                     YES (ver 0.10.29)
--       app:                       YES (ver 0.10.29)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 0.10.29)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 0.10.29)
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l (ver 0.6.3)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     8.2.1 [8.2.1]
--          at:                     /path/to/opencv-build/opencv-3.0.0-beta/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use TBB:                     NO
--     Use OpenMP:                  NO
--     Use GCD                      NO
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /path/to/opencv-build/opencv-3.0.0-beta/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /path/to/venv/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.5)
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 NO
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /path/to/venv/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:
--     mex:                         NO
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Build Documentation:         NO
--     Sphinx:                      NO
--     PdfLaTeX compiler:           NO
--     PlantUML:                    NO
--     Doxygen:                     YES (/usr/bin/doxygen)
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /path/to/opencv-build/opencv-3.0.0-beta/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/opencv-build/opencv-3.0.0-beta/build
```

How to fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Please post more of your CMake output.  I assume you ran `make` and `make install` afterward?  Do a `find / -name cv2.so` for starters.

Comment: @msmith81886 i have updated with traceback

Answer (score 0):

So the PythonLibs error seems to be the smoking gun.  In Centos, I believe the package you are missing is `python-devel`.  That will give you the development libraries needed.

In addition, I would highly recommend installing the devtoolset package from RHEL software collections.  This is essential if you want Python 2.7 and Python 3.3.  Otherwise, you are stuck with 2.6.

https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL

Next, I would recommend installing gstreamer and ffmpeg for video support.  You can grab gstreamer on the Centos repo and ffmpeg on the repoforge repository.

http://repoforge.org/